ubuntu I can't mount ntfs partition
I have a ntfs partition for data that I use with ubuntu and win 10
Now I can't use it in ubuntu but in win 10 it works
I see error muonting
how can I do?

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; nor actual clues as to what error message(s) you get.   If using a terminal to mount, providing the command and messages pasted into your question would be best, however if using a GUI tool, the messages may be in logs & require you to look. We can't help with error messages unless details are provided to us.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled? The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot" - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
